# How to auto reassemble mdadm raid 10 array on boot?

Tags: linux-mint, mdadm

Using Linux Mint 18

I have created a raid 10 array of 4 disks using `mdadm`. I then updated `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`. It contains an ARRAY entry with only the UUID - no `/dev/sdX`. I then executed `update-initramfs -u`.

Everything is fine when I remove a hdd sata cable to simulate total hdd failure. The array still works in degraded mode and can be repaired.

The problem is, when I shut down the machine and then remove the sata cable.
Then my raid array won't start up and all remaining 3 drives are reported as spares. I can then use `mdadm` to manually rescan and reassemble a degraded array using 3 remaining drives, but I would like that to happen automatically on boot. I avoid using `/dev/sdX` anywhere, but maybe the device names are being used somewhere in the system anyway? And all drives are lost, because if I remove `/dev/sda`, then `/dev/sd[b-d]` change names?

I did try to add `md-mod.start_dirty_degraded=1` as kernel parameter, but it did not help.